# Manage local emails on two Mac computers

Tags: email, ms-office

I use Outlook for Mac on my iMac and my Macbook (that I use when I travel).
Due to storage limitations in my employers Exchange servers, I need to store emails locally (as well on the server).
Is there any ways to have access to the locally stored emails on both my iMac and MacBook? Easy ways prefered ...

Comment: Are you allowed by your employer to have the data (i.e. mail) on external systems?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Gmail's powerful IMAP features to keep your emails synced on both computers.

I have set this up for lots of people and it works great.

Get a Gmail account and go to settings - Accounts and Import.

You will have to set it up to check mail using POP3 and enter your mail server settings.  Next set up Send mail as choose Send mail from another address then put your outgoing smtp settings.

Next go to the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab and enable IMAP and click on the Configuration instructions and it will give you the settings to enter into Apple Mail.

Once your Apple Mail is set up on both computers it will keep all your messages synced.  You can also set it up on your iphone or Android.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this suggestion. One question, how safe is gmail? And how safe is Google? Do they read/index emails for searching? Another question I have is regarding POP3, would this mean that all the email on my company server are deleted as part of the process, or are they still there? Thanks again. Niklas

Comment: On the POP 3 settings there is a check box to choose whether or not to leave a copy of the messages on the mail server.  I find it very secure as long as you select force https in the settings.  It's not like Yahoo where accounts get hacked all the time.  Google does save archives but they don't use them for anything unless subpoenaed by a court of law.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a simple way to do this.  You could share your Mail folder on one of the machines and create a link to it on the other machine - or you could involve another email server.  I would do the latter.  Get an IMAP emil account, even a gmail or better yet a google apps account.  Add the email address (using IMAP,) at work, and when you need to move stuff onto the local machine due to storage restriction, instead of moving it onto the local machine, move it into your IMAP account.  It will be sync'd since IMAP does syncing natively.  All you'd have to do then is set up the IMAP account on the other computer as well.